# What is the best way to present source code, both offline and in books?

Tags: fonts, typography

Being somewhat typographically obsessed, I am curious: what is the best way to present code - both online and offline. In particular, I'm interested in:

- What kinds of typefaces and sizes work best online and offline? Is it better to use proportional fonts for code (e.g., like Stroustrup does in 'The C++ Programming Language')? Serif, sans-serif, or mixed?
- How should code be annotated - with the typical `// comment` markup, or perhaps just with a different typeface (and no comment tags)?
- Is it worth drawing arrows (or something similar) to show how different blocks of code relate to one another?
- Does showing code in several columns side-by-side work at all?
- Does anyone need things like line numbering, altering lines, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer most of the questions, but you might be interested in reading up on [Literate Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming).  The gist of it is that you write your code and documentation in the same document, and it is formatted for web or print or whatever.  And when I say documentation here, it's not usually one-line snippets of documentation, but whole paragraphs or pages describing what's going on in the program.

Comment: Wow, I can sort of relate to this concept in the way that, say, Cucumber works (BDD tests written in plain English). However, our programming languages aren't there yet, and I find that large comments block presented as comments (rather than ordinary text) are extremely tedious to read. Maybe it's me, but I find reading monospaced text harder that reading proportionally spaced text.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me add my vote against proportional fonts, as used by BS in TC++PL. It really drives me nuts! Similarly Soctt Meyers in Effective STL, with the added horror of some nasty hightlighting.

For me, the classic book on programming will always be K&R, as I don't think it has ever been improved on for clarity of presentation. so I would suggest copying it slavishly.

Comment: There's one added trouble with monospaced fonts: you can't pack as many characters in a line. And with space being in short supply (especially for long code blocks), I can sort of see why some people go with 'traditional' serif fonts.

Comment: That "packing lots onto a line" is one of the main reasons I don't like proportional fonts for code!

Answer (score 1):

I like the use of an extended character-set when writing dummy code in text. The **LaTeX** fonts for code and math markup work well.

A good example would be using a left arrow for assignment or binding rather than `=`. The best examples of code in books I have seen has been things like the Dragon Book or TAOCP. I think a mixture of mathematical etymology due to the ability to render those characters and a relation to common syntax is great.

A mixture of the usual fixed-courier type fonts and advanced math markup available through Computer Modern in LaTeX I think works well for readers of a mathematical disposition ... and it can look very nice.

Comment: Ugh, this must be tough from the typesetting point of view. For the web, you need to generate images, for print you need to have a way of cleanly mixing code and math notation.

I like the idea, but I don't find math notation useful. Maybe for algorithms and such, but not for general-purpose 'business code'.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things that cross my mind:

- Limit the number of lines to a minimum
- Line numbers only when needed
- You can certainly use different fonts, but what about a different background? Like a light gray? Box your code and I think there is no problem in putting two boxes next to each other.
- Depends on the costs, but what about coloring certain elements - like most IDEs do -?
- Write working, real world code! Therefore I would suggest to use the normal // comment style and not just a different font.

Answer (score 1):

- I would use a monopaced font like
  Consolas.
- Since comments usually appear as just a different color (at least in the IDEs i've seen), i'd leave them in as-is.
- What do you mean by "show how blocks relate to each other"? indicate where functions, if statements, etc. start and end? if so, it might be helpful; i honestly don't know.
- It might work if you were comparing a couple of chunks of code to indicate some subtle difference that would not work in one but work in another, but i don't see much use for it beyond that.
- Line numbers might help if you make references like "go to line XYZ in the previous code sample".